# Conditions for inner product sign with a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, linear-transformations, inner-products

I need to find properties for the following inner products situation.

Let $u,v\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ with inner product usual in $\mathbb{R}$ and let $A\in\mathbb{M}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ a real matrix with real coeficients. I need to find conditions (whatever they are) such as
$$\langle u,v \rangle >0 \implies \langle Au,Av \rangle >0$$

For example if $A$ is a orthogonal matriz the sign is preserve and even more the value is the same but I would like to know if there is a "minimum" condition for this situation to happen.

On the other hand I want to emphasize that $A$ is the linearization of any diffeomorphism, that is, A is the derivative of someone, for example I understand that if my diffeomorphism is convex then its linearization will be positive definite (I could be wrong)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can equivalently write your requirement as
$$
\langle u,v \rangle > 0 \implies \langle u, A^TAv\rangle > 0.
$$
So, it suffices to find conditions on $M = A^TA$ such that $\langle u,v \rangle > 0 \implies \langle u, M v\rangle > 0$. The answer to this question is that $M$ must be a multiple of the identity.

If $M$ is not a multiple of the identity matrix, then there exists a (non-zero) vector $v$ such that $Mv$ is not a multiple of $v$ (cf. [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/146416/81360) for instance). Let $u$ be given by
$$
u = \frac 12 \left(\frac{v}{\|v\|} - \frac{Mv}{\|Mv\|}\right).
$$
Using the [Cauchy-Schwarz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) inequality, deduce that $\langle u,v\rangle > 0$, but $\langle u,Mv \rangle < 0$.

Thus, we conclude that $A^TA$ must be a multiple of the identity matrix. This in turn implies that $A$ must be a multiple of an orthogonal matrix.

Comment: wow, this is cool, you can't imagine how much you help me. my only question is how you applied CS there

Comment: @StrinoX3 For a unit vector $w$, $\langle x,w \rangle \leq \|x\|$, with equality *if and only if* $x$ is a (positive) multiple of $w$.