# Given a matrix A, how to find  B such that AB=BA

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A = \begin{pmatrix}
1 &  1& 1\\ 
1 & 2 &3 \\ 
1 &4  & 5
\end{pmatrix}$ and  $D = \begin{pmatrix}
2 &  0& 0\\ 
0 & 3 &0 \\ 
0 &0  & 5
\end{pmatrix}$.

It is found that *right-multiplication* by D multiplies each *column* of A by the corresponding diagonal entry of D, whereas *left-multiplication* by D multiplies each *row* of A by the corresponding diagonal entry of D.

Construct a 3 x 3 matrix B, not the identity matrix or zero matrix, such that $AB=BA$.

Comment: What's wrong with $2I$?

Comment: $B = A$ or $B = A^2$, etc., will also work.  More generally you want to find $B$ which is simultaneously diagonalizable with $A$.

Comment: Hehe, thanks. I was rather trying to construct B using the hint in the middle paragraph and had missed the obvious answers.

Comment: possible duplicates: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92480/, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170241/

Comment: The diagonal hint may be misleading, any diagonal matrix satisfying the requirements is necessarily a multiple of the identity matrix.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that the determinant of $A$ is $-2$, so your matrix is invertible i.e. there exists some matrix $B=A^{-1}$ such that $AB=BA=I$. If I calculated this correctly 
$$B = \begin{pmatrix}
1 &  1/2& -1/2\\ 
1 & -2 &1 \\ 
-1 & 3/2  & -1/2
\end{pmatrix}.$$

Answer (score 5):

As Alex Becker said, we could use any scalar multiple of $I$ or $A^n$ where $A^n = A\cdot A \dots A$ where $A$ is multiplied by itself $A$ times.  We could also use $A^{-1}$ or $(A^{-1})^n$.

Suppose we have any matrices $B$ and $C$ that satisfy $AB=BA$ and $AC=CA$.  Then, $A(c_1 B + c_2 C) = c_1 A B + c_2 A C = c_1 BA + c_2 CA = (c_1 B + c_2 C)A$.

From this we conclude that the collection of all matrices that commute with $A$ (under matrix multiplication) forms a vector space, since any linear combinations of matrices that commute with $A$ will also commute with $A$.

Comment: Does anyone know what is the basis for this vector space?

Comment: Finding a basis can get quite complicated. If $A$ is diagonalizable it is quite easy, but if $A$ is in Jordan normal form with Jordan blocks of size greater than $1$, determining the matrices which commute with $A$ can get quite tricky, even if $A$ has only the eigenvalue $1$ or $0$.

Answer (score 3):

Notice that $A$ is diagonalizable, so any matirx with the same eigenvectors will commute with $A$, for example

$$B = \begin{pmatrix}
0.2481 & 0.31385 & -0.034765 \\ 
0.48816 & -0.65821 & 0.76725 \\ 
-0.20907 & 1.0811 & 0.28335
\end{pmatrix}$$