# When do two $n \times n$ matrices $A, B$ have the property that $AB = BA$?

Tags: matrices

As we all know that two $n \times n$ matrices $A, B$
need not have the relation $AB = BA.$ But when do two $n \times n$ matrices have such a property?

Comment: I think an answer is much longer than you would expect. Try searching necessary and sufficient conditions for matrices to commute if no one gives an answer here. I see some articles on the topic.

Comment: @Eoin: Ah, thanks so much. I was just working through linear algebra material and this question was triggered. After googling about this topic, I felt it would be better to ask here to see if some experts may help out with.

Comment: haha yeah I thought so. I'm glad someone had a fairly short answer after looking at the articles.

Comment: You might take a look at this [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170241/when-is-matrix-multiplication-commutative)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To give a completely general answer is too complicated to be of general use. The simplest nice case: if $A$ and $B$ are diagonalizable and share the same eigenspaces, then they commute. This is because sharing the same eigenspaces implies that $A$ and $B$ can be simultaneously diagonalized, i.e. $A=CDC^{-1}$ and $B=CD'C^{-1}$ where $D,D'$ are diagonal and thus commute. This is also a necessary condition among diagonalizable matrices, that is, commuting diagonalizable matrices can be simultaneously diagonalized.

Answer (score 1):

While I am not aware of any *necessary **and** sufficient* condition for matrices to commute with $A\in K^{n\times n}$, it *is* possible to completely characterise the set of matrices that commute with $A\in \mathbb R^{2\times 2}$ (and other special cases) by setting up a system of equations equating the individual coefficients of the two products $AB$ and $BA$ and finding the conditions for those equations to be fulfilled.

For small dimensions, this yields quite usable results. An explicit example for the $2 \times 2$ case can be found [here](http://martin-thoma.com/when-is-matrix-multiplication-commutative/).