# Matrix multiplication proofs

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A,B$ be a $n × n$ matrices

Prove or disprove:

$(A + B)^2 = A^2 + 2AB + B^2$

$A^3− I = (A − I) (A^2 + A + I)$

I'm having trouble figuring this out, how can I prove the first one? the only thing that comes in my mind from $(a+b)^2$ is to make it $a^2+2ab+b^2$, same for the second one

thanks

Comment: What should this symbol after the paranthesis of the rhs of the 2nd equation be? Coud you please fix that?

Comment: I fixed it, is it ok now?

Comment: There is still an unknown symbol infront of the $A^2$, should the second equation just be $A^3− I = (A − I) (A^2 + A + I)$ ? This is true since the distributive holds in any ring (and $n\times n$ matrices form a ring).

Comment: Yes, and that's exactly how I see it from my PC

Comment: Ok, I fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is not correct since [matrix multiplication is not commutative in the general case](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Matrix_Multiplication_is_Not_Commutative).

$$
\begin{align*}
{(A + B)^2} &= (A + B) (A + B) = A^2 + AB + BA + B^2 \\
&\neq A^2 + 2AB + B^2 \text{ (in the general case)}
\end{align*}
$$

For the second one (since distributivity holds), you can simply work out out as follows (note that $M_{n \times n}I_n = I_nM_{n \times n} = M_{n \times n}$):

$$
\begin{align*}
(A - I)(A^2 + A + I) &= A^3 + A^2 + AI - IA^2 - IA - I^2 \\
&= A^3 + A^2 + A - A^2 - A - I = A^3 - I
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: There are matrices where this inequality does not hold ($A=B=I$) so you should rather give a concrete counterexample for disproving it, for example $A = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ and $B = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: @flawr: You are absolutely correct. I edited my answer and wrote that it doesn't hold in the general case, so I think your example will serve well. If anyone is interested when commutativity _does hold_, he/she can read more [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170241/when-is-matrix-multiplication-commutative).

Comment: @flawr The entire expression is equivalent to $AB = BA$, so merely quoting that matrix multiplication is not commutative in general suffices. An explicit example is good, of course!