# Find if two matrices are commutative

Tags: matrices

I'm triyng to do this  exercize :

$$n \in \mathbb{N^*}, \ D_1,D_2,P \ \in \mathbb{M}_n(\mathbb{C})\ \text{with} \ D_1,D_2 \ \text{diagonals} \ \text{and} \ P \ \text{an invertible matrix}. \\\text{Let} \ A=PD_1P^{-1}, B=PD_2P^{-1}. \text{Are A and B  commutative} ? $$

How is it possible to answer this without knowing more information on the matrices ?

Thanks you

Comment: Did you try computing $AB$ and $BA$?

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**: $D_1$ and $D_2$ do commute

Comment: thanks for your answer, with the information here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170241/when-is-matrix-multiplication-commutative I managed to proove it.

Comment: Yes, thats right. A simple matter of computation now will give you $AB=BA$