# How can we write examples of commutative and anticommutative matrices?

Tags: matrices

How can we write examples of commutative and anticommutative matrices? I know how to write matrices A and B both nonzero but AB = 0.  Similarly I want to know if there is a technique of writing anticommutative matrices and commutative matrices.

Comment: [possible duplicate](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170241/when-is-matrix-multiplication-commutative)?

Comment: I checked before posting.  I did not find this question posted before.

Comment: You want to know how to *find* matrices with $AB = BA$ or $AB = -BA$? And presumably not *all* matrices like that, just examples? I just want to make sure I understand.

Comment: Yes.  If I start with some A, do I have a way of finding B such that AB is either commutative or anticommutative?  If for every A it is not possible, is there a way of starting with only A such that I will be able to find B?

Comment: For example, the matrices should be of even order, if they are to be anticommutative, so to write a anticommutative matrix we should start with an even order matrix A.  There may be further constraints on A and B.