# Give two examples of a non-zero matrix $\textbf{A}$ such that $\textbf{AX} = \textbf{XA}$

Tags: matrices

Matrix $\textbf{A} = \begin{bmatrix}2&-1\\-1&1\end{bmatrix}.$

Give two examples of a non-zero matrix $\textbf{A}$ such that $\textbf{AX} = \textbf{XA}$?

Find the general form of $\textbf{AX}$?

Comment: There is the trivial case of the identity matrix.  And and then there are matrices which you can find if you know some things about eigenvectors.

Comment: Did you for ALL matrices $\mathbf{X} \text{ ?}$ If so, it would be better to say so. $\qquad$

Comment: This might be helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170241/when-is-matrix-multiplication-commutative

Answer (score 0):

The characteristic and minimal polynomials coincide, $\lambda^2 - 3 \lambda + 1.$ Therefore all matrices that commute with $A$ are polynomials in $A,$ by Cayley-Hamilton we can take these as
$$  xI + y A  $$

see  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92480/given-a-matrix-is-there-always-another-matrix-which-commutes-with-it/92832#92832

Or you can write
$$
X = 
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
p & q \\
r & s
\end{array}
\right)
$$
and write out the matrix $AX-XA$ and set all four matrix entries to zero. You get  simple equations restricting the entries of $X.$