# Finding two non-zero matrices where $AX = BA$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a question where I have a matrix $$A=\begin{bmatrix}2&-1\\-1&1\end{bmatrix}$$ and I need to find two examples of a non-zero matrix $X$ such that $AX = XA$. My first matrix is \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix} the identity matrix but I cant think of another one. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm confused. is $A$ given or not given?

Comment: Do you mean $AB = BA$? Your question as it stands doesn't really make sense to me.

Comment: How about $B = \begin{bmatrix} -1 & 1\\1& 0 \end{bmatrix}$ then $BA = AB$

Comment: I think the OP means $A$ is given, $X$ and $B$ are unknown.

Comment: same question yesterday https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2520448/give-two-examples-of-a-non-zero-matrix-textbfa-such-that-textbfax-te

Answer (score 2):

How about $B=A=X$ then $AB = A^2 = BA$?

Comment: probably was really this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2520448/give-two-examples-of-a-non-zero-matrix-textbfa-such-that-textbfax-te

Answer (score 1):

So we have
$$A = \left[ \begin{array}{c c} 2 & -1 \\ -1 & 1 \end{array} \right]$$
Some simple answers include first taking
$$X = \left[ \begin{array}{c c} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{array} \right]$$
Which gives
$$AX = \left[ \begin{array}{c c} 2 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 \end{array} \right]$$
It's not too hard to guess and check to find
$$B = \left[ \begin{array}{c c} 2 & 2 \\ -1 & -1 \end{array} \right]$$
does the trick.

Comment: probably was really this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2520448/give-two-examples-of-a-non-zero-matrix-textbfa-such-that-textbfax-t