# Give two specific examples of a non-zero matrix X such that: AX = XA.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

If matrix A = \begin{bmatrix}3&1\\-2&-1\end{bmatrix}

I am trying to give two specific examples of a non-zero matrix X such that: AX = XA.

so far I let X = \begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}

And so AX = XA, and I multiplied X and A respectivley to give the linear equations:

3a + c = 3a - 2b

3b + d = a - b

-2a + c = 3c - 2d

-2b - d = c - d

I believe i am supposed to show this in matrix form and solve the system to get a 4x4 matrix containing expressions with two variables where any number can be substituted so that AX = XA. However I am unsure on how to do this and need some help.

Comment: Here are some examples: $X=A,A^p,A^{-1}, I$

Comment: I think that any diagonal matrix would do the job.

Comment: @TitoEliatron Certainly not. Multiplying on the left by a diagonal matrix has the effect of multiplying rows by the respective diagonal elements, while multiplying on the right has the same effect of columns.

Comment: Funny: [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2520448/give-two-examples-of-a-non-zero-matrix-textbfa-such-that-textbfax-te?rq=1) (and the [same](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2522260/finding-two-non-zero-matrices-where-ax-ba) one day later), exactly one year ago: looks like a teacher is reusing the same exercise again and again, and students feel like asking on MSE again and again.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Actually, the user name has already been deleted, see above.

Answer (score 3):

The identity matrix always works, so that's one example.

$X=A$ always works, since if $X=A$, then $AX=A^2=XA$, so that's another one.

Answer (score 0):

Any nonzero multiple, $t\cdot I$, of the identity matrix.