# What is the generalised condition for two matrices to commute?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am stuck in finding the generalised condition for two matrices of any order to commute over each other i.e.

$$AB=BA$$

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170241/when-is-matrix-multiplication-commutative).

Comment: Also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/236212/simultaneously-diagonalizable-proof), which talks about the non-diagonalizable case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matrix multiplication is always **commutative** when (i) one of the matrices is the Identity matrix (ii) One of the matrix is the Zero matrix. (iii) both matrices are Diagonal matrices.

Moreover, Two matrices that are simultaneously diagonalizable are always commutative.

Becase $A$ and $B$ are simultaneously diagonalizable, then a matrix $T$ exists, such that $D_A = S^{-1} \cdot A \cdot S$ and $D_B = S^{-1} \cdot B \cdot S$
\begin{align}
A \cdot B &= S \cdot D_A S^{-1} \cdot  S \cdot D_B \cdot S^{-1}  \rm {~~as ~}(S^{-1}S = I)\\
&= S \cdot D_A \cdot D_B \cdot S^{-1} \\
&= S \cdot D_B \cdot D_A \cdot S^{-1} \\
&= S \cdot D_B \cdot S^{-1} \cdot  S \cdot D_A \cdot S^{-1} \\
&= B \cdot A
\end{align}

Comment: Rotation matrices are not commutative. See the first paragraph [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_rotation_group).

Comment: I knew 2D rotation matrix are commutative. Thanks for point out the mistake. Appreciate it :-)