# If the matrix of a linear map is independent from the basis, then the map is a multiple of the identity map.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over $F$, and let
$$T:V\to V$$
be a linear map.

Suppose that given any two bases $B$ and $C$ for $V$, we have that the matrix of $T$ with respect $B$ is equal to that with respect to $C$.

How can we show that this implies that there exists some $\lambda\in F$ such that $T(v)=\lambda v$, $\forall v\in V$?

Comment: Closely related: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/27808/8157

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $A$ be the matrix of $T$. Suppose $Tv_1=v_2$ for some vectors $v_1,v_2$ that are not linearly dependent. Extend $\{v_1,v_2\}$ to a basis $\{v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n\}$ of $V$. By assumption, the matrices of $T$ w.r.t. the ordered bases $\{v_1,v_2,v_3,\ldots,v_n\}$ and $\{v_2,v_1,v_3,\ldots,v_n\}$ must both be equal to $A$. Therefore $Tv_2=v_1$. But then $T(v_1+v_2)=v_1+v_2\not=v_1-v_2$. Hence the matrix of $T$ w.r.t. the ordered basis $\{v_1+v_2,\ v_1-v_2,\ v_3,\ldots, v_n\}$ would be different from $A$, which is a contradiction.

Therefore, for every vector $v\in V$, $Tv$ and $v$ must be linearly dependent, i.e. $Tv=\lambda_vv$ for some scalar $\lambda_v$. Let $v$ be the first vector in an ordered basis of $V$, we see that $\lambda_v$ is equal to the $(1,1)$-th entry of $A$, which is a constant. Hence the result follows.

Comment: Thanks. By "not linearly independent" I guess you mean "not linearly dependent", right? The second sentence.

Comment: @Spenser Thanks for catching the typo. It's now corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: This is equivalent to say that any nonzero vector is an eigenvector of $T$

Comment: Would you care to elaborate? I don't see how it is equivalent.