# If $f$ commutes with every linear transformation, it's a scalar multiple of the identity

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm dealing with a problem related to linear transformation.

**Problem**: Let $f \in L\left( V \right)$, where 
$L\left( V \right)$ is the set of all linear operators on $V$. Prove that if 
$fg = gf$ for all $g \in L\left( V \right)$, then $f = ai$, where $a$ is a scalar and $i$ is identity map.

I can't go on. Is there any hint?

Comment: Are you assuming $\dim V < \infty$?

Comment: There isn't any restriction.

Comment: I'm sure someone asked about this just the other day (but it isn't easy to find it when everyone uses subjects like "problem about linear transformations").

Comment: The finite dimensional case is done at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27808/a-linear-operator-commuting-with-all-such-operators-is-a-scalar-multiple-of-the and Robert Israel says his answer works in the infinite-dimensional case, given the Axiom of Choice.