# Abelian Matrices

Tags: group-theory

I'm working on some beginner group theory, and I understand that there is an
issue where most matrices are not commutative (i.e. Abelian).  However, I am
interested in solving for the properties of matrices that make them Abelian. 
I was wondering, what is a good way to start exploring the properties of
matrices that could make them Abelian?  I haven't done much of this 
"exploratory math" proofs, but I hear it is good practice.

Comment: What does it mean for a matrix to be commutative? Do you mean a matrix which commutes with every other?

Comment: It is not so much that a specific *matrix* has the property, but rather that two matrices *together* commute.  The matrices that commute with *all* other matrices are quite uninteresting as they are simply scalar multiples of the identity matrix.  You can, however, find $A$ and $B$ such that $AB=BA$ with neither being a scalar multiple of the identity.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A linear operator commuting with all such operators is a scalar multiple of the identity.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27808/a-linear-operator-commuting-with-all-such-operators-is-a-scalar-multiple-of-the)

Comment: @JMoravitz Yes, this is most likely what the OP means, but it's a little disheartening to hear the OP excited about *exploring* her idea only for you to spoil the answer in the comments. :(

Comment: If you mean, *What are the $n \times n$ matrices $A$ such that $AB = BA $for all $n \times n$ matrices $B$?* I'd suggest writing down a general matrix $A$ and looking for conditions on the entries $a_{ij}$ of $A$ such that $A$ commutes with some simple matrices $B$. For purposes of matrix multiplication, the simplest matrices that are not multiplies of $I$ are the matrices $E_{ij}$, which respectively have entry $e_{ij} = 1$ and all other entries zero.

Comment: It might be interesting for you to consider the conditions on a *set* of matrices needed for any two matrices in the set to commute with each other.  For instance, a set containing the identity matrix and (any) one other matrix has this property.  Are there larger sets that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided that you mean by "$A$ an abelian matrix" the following :

$$A\text{ is a matrix  such that } BA=AB\text{ for all matrices }B$$

Usually we say that "$A$ is central".

Then it is indeed an interesting exercise. A first approach would be to write down  the equations (in the coefficients of $A$) given by $AB=BA$ for some $B$'s nd try to understand what is going on. This takes a lot of time and is not the best approach.

The best approach is to think of matrices as endomorphisms of some vector space. Indeed say you work over a field $K$ and matrices of size $n$.

Define $E:=K^n$, it has a canonical base $e_1,...,e_n$.

If $M$ is a matrix in $M_{n,n}(K)$ then $M$ can be seen as an endomorphism of $E$ by sending $e_i$ to the vector $M.e_i$.

If you have $AB=BA$ then the associated endomorphisms commute as well. Try now to prove the following lemma :

> If $E$ is a $K$-vectorial space, $f$ and $g$ are two linear applications from $E$ to $E$. The relation $fg=gf$ implies that any eigenspace of $f$ is stable by $g$.

After you have done this you conclude that $A$ (as an endomorphism) stabilizes every eigenspace of every matrix. Uses this to show that $Vect(e_1)$,...,$Vect(e_n)$ and $Vect(e_1+...+e_n)$ are all stable by $A$ and conclude.