# A diagonal matrix is commutative with very square matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $A$ is a diagonal matrix of order $3\times3$ is commutative with every square matrix of order $3\times3$ under multiplication and $trace(A) =12$, then the value of $|A|$ is :

Could someone give me hint to get through this problem

Comment: Is $\vert A\vert$ the determinant?

Comment: @Mandrathax yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that commuting with any square matrix implies (for example shown in the answers [to this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/27808/211913))$$A=\begin{pmatrix}a&0&0\\0&a&0\\0&0&a\end{pmatrix}.$$

I think you can take it from here.

Answer (score 2):

The **only** matrices of order $\;\ge2\;$ that commute with *any* other matrix of the same order are the scalar ones, so

$$A=kI\implies 12=Tr(A)=3k\implies k=4\implies \det A=4^3=64$$