# Prove that there exists $\lambda \in F$ such that $A=\lambda.I_n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Assume that $A \in M_{n}(F)$ is a matrix, such that for each $B \in M_n(F)$ we have $AB=BA$.

> Prove that there exists $\lambda \in F$ such that $A=\lambda.I_n$

Note 1 : $F$ is a field.

Note 2 : This question should be solved without the use of vectors and determinants. Unfortunately, I don't know where to start ! I mean, in general form, When we want to prove that something exists, We should find it. But i don't know how !

Comment: See here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27808/a-linear-operator-commuting-with-all-such-operators-is-a-scalar-multiple-of-the

Comment: @carmichael561 i don't know anything about vector spaces :) keep it simple please :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the set of matrix units $\{E_{kj}\}$, where $E_{kj}$ is the matrix with a $1$ in the $k,j$ entry and zeroes elsewhere. The hypothesis is that $A$ commutes with all these. Note also that 
$$
A=\sum_{k,j}a_{kj}E_{kj}
$$
and that 
$$
E_{kj}E_{st}=\delta_{j,s}\,E_{kt},\ \ \ \sum_kE_{kk}=I.
$$
So, for instance, for fixed $k$ and $j$ with $k\ne j$,
$$
a_{kj}E_{kj}=E_{kk}AE_{jj}=E_{kk}E_{jj}A=0.
$$
So $a_{kj}=0$. As we can do this for all $k\ne j$, we get that $A$ is diagonal: $$ A=\sum_ka_{kk}E_{kk}.$$ Now, for any $k$,
$$
a_{11}E_{k1}=E_{k1}A=AE_{k1}=a_{kk}E_{k1}
$$
and then $a_{kk}=a_{11}$. Thus, 
$$
A=\sum_ka_{11}E_{kk}=a_{11}\,I.
$$