# What is the linear transformation which can commute with all projections?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27808/a-linear-operator-commuting-with-all-such-operators-is-a-scalar-multiple-of-the) question and I have a new question which is a special form of it:
what can we say about a linear function which can commute with every projections?

Comment: Some additional info may be necessary.

Comment: The condition is as same as the linked question...

Comment: I know that the dimension is finite...

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry on my tablet didn't show up before.

Comment: @Bernard : here communicate means : EP=PE. E and P are linear transformation and P is projection

Comment: @Bernard thanks it was a typo mistake

Comment: @fateme jl: That makes it clear.I'm addict to typos myself :o) I've deleted my other comments (and will delete this one in a moment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All such maps are some multiple of the identity.

Let $p$ be a projection onto a subspace $V$. If $v\in V$ then $p(v)=v$. So if $f$ commutes with $p$ and $v\in V$ we have $f(v)=f(p(v))=p(f(v))\in V$, so $f$ sends $V$ to a subspace of $V$. So if $f$ commutes with every projector it sends every subspace to a subspace of that subspace.

So by looking at the one dimensional subspaces we see that for every vector $v$ we have $f(v)=\lambda v$ for some $\lambda$. I claim that in fact this must be the same $\lambda$ for each vector. Suppose $f(v)=\lambda v$ and $f(w)=\mu w$. Then

$$f(v+w)=\lambda v+\mu w,$$
and this must equal $\nu(v+w)$ for some $\nu$. So $(\lambda-\nu)v=(\nu-\mu)w$. If $v$ and $w$ point in different directions this can only happen if both sides are $0$, so $\lambda=\nu=\mu$.

Hence $f$ is $\lambda$ times the identity for some $\lambda$.

Comment: I don't know why here we have : f(v)=f(p(v))

Comment: @fatemejl $v=p(v)$ because $v\in V$ and $p$ is a projector that projects onto $V$. So $f(v)=f(p(v))$.

Comment: Can you explain more about the equality? I'm a bit confused. I see no necessity for holding this equality for a projector like p. thanks for your help

Comment: The definition of projector requires that $p^2=p$. If $V$ is the image of $p$ and $v\in V$ then $v=p(v')$ for some $v'$. So $p(v)=p(p(v'))=p(v')=v$.

Comment: in last part of the proof that you claim this multiplicity is unique, what will happen if we choose v and w from different subspaces?

Comment: If they point in different directions then my proof works because then the only way to have $(\lambda -\nu)v=(\nu-\mu)w$ is to have $(\lambda -\nu)v=0$ and $(\nu-\mu)w=0$. If $v$ and $w$ point in the same direction then we can write $w=\alpha v$ for some number $\alpha$ and then $f(w)=f(\alpha v)=\alpha f(v)=\alpha\lambda v=\lambda\alpha v=\lambda w$, so that case works too.

Comment: I mean if you choose two different vector with different directions, how you claim that f(v+w) is the multiple of v+w?

Comment: we know that this holds in the subspaces, not all the space.

Comment: We know that $f$ takes *every* subspace into itself. So in particular the one-dimensional subspace spanned by $v+w$ gets taken into itself. So $v+w$ gets mapped to some multiple of itself.

Comment: can you explain why p(f(v)) is a member of V? how we know that f(v) is also a member of V?

Comment: The image of $p$ is $V$, so $p$ of anything is in $V$. In particular $p(f(v))$ is in $V$.